# Firebase onMessage not triggered on ios Flutter when notification is sent through APNS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problems with FirebaseMessaging package for push notifications. The onMessage event is not triggered

Well, what the title says. When I send notifications using the Firebase tools (firebase console or API) I receive notifications and the callbacks are triggered, but when the notification is sent using APNs, it shows the notification (if I set the setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions) but the onMessage isn't triggered.

For this app, I need full control of notifications, so I need to receive the data on onMessage first, then check if I want to show it or not, if I want to save it or not, and other conditions.

This works for Android, but for iOS it doesn't.

Does firebase_messaging work for this case? What can I do to listen when a notification is received via APNs?

Note: I'm testing it on a real device and I have the APNs key on firebase (I mean, if I set setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions and it shows the notification, I think the configuration is right).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. but still not able to find out the solution for same. please let me know if anyone knows the solution for the above issue.

Comment: I shared my solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, here is the answer

[https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4300#issuecomment-916883580][1]

I did a fork to the package, added it to my project's package folder, and made that condition always true.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem, sending the below APNS push notification payload;

```
{
  "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"default\":\"Test\",\"data\":{\"jobType\":\"DeviceEventCheck\"},\"gcm.message_id\":\"123456\",\"priority\":\"high\",\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"Title\",\"body\":\"Body\"},\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}"
}
```

above solution work form me

Comment: That's a good option too if you have control of the backend or notification service

Comment: Yes, @LeaGonzálezCuello